# Display a variable from an array in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a function in my helper

```
function somethingOrOther($id)
{
      $posts = Posts::where('author_id', $id);
      $posts_count = [];
      $posts_count['total'] = $posts->count();
      $posts_count['published'] = $posts->where('status', 'published')->count();
      $posts_count['draft'] = $posts->where('status', 'draft')->count();

      return $posts_count;
}
```

and this function works perfectly fine. But now I'm trying use it in this function in a controller to return it to a view

```
public function profile($id)
    {
      $posts_count[]= somethingOrOther($id);

      return view ('display.profile')->withPosts_count($posts_count['total'])->withPosts_published_count($posts_count['published'])->withPosts_draft_count($posts_count['draft']);
}
```

But I get an error of 'Undefined index: total'. What do I need to do to separately return the array values of $posts_count?

Comment: try this to see what it returns please
$posts_count[]= somethingOrOther($id);
dd($posts_count);

Comment: I did. And it returns the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can just do

```
$posts_count= somethingOrOther($id);
```

and then return it like

```
return view ('display.profile',["posts_count" => $posts_count]);
```

and in blade get it like

```
{{$posts_count["total"]}}
```

Comment: and what does it return if you do this in blade

<?php var_dump($posts_count); ?>

Comment: It's not null. array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["total"]=> int(61) ["published"]=> int(46) ["draft"]=> int(0) } } --}}. It's just that it says 'Undefined index: total in the view'

Comment: The array is being saved as an index, if you do {{$posts_count[0]["total"]}} it probably works.

Comment: here you're assigning the array that comes to a function to another array... you probably just need $posts_count= somethingOrOther($id); and not $posts_count[] = somethingOrOther($id);

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$post_count = $this->somethingOrOther($id);
if ( !$post_count ) {
     return "no posts for this author";
}
...
return view('display.profile', compact('post_count'));
```

In view

```
{{ $post_count['total'] }}
```

Comment: I do not have a problem with my post count. I have a problem with passing my array from controller to view.

Comment: Check my update. And you need to check, in the helper, if `$posts` is not empty. Always check for null.

Comment: I checked my posts with dd and my array of $posts_count is not null. 'Total','Published,'draft' all have the correct count.. So I tried your code but it  has an error in view 'Undefined index: total''..

Comment: Are you writing 'total' or 'Total' with capital?. Please show the result of dd

Comment: no not in capital my bad. But here's the dd: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "total" => 61
    "published" => 46
    "draft" => 0
  ]
]

Comment: in my example I did `$post_count = ...` in your example you are doing `$post_count[] = ...` therefore you have a nested array. Do `{{ $post_count[0]["total"] }}`